# Google colab: problem in the train of YOLOv4-tiny-Darknet-Roboflow

Tags: google-colaboratory, yolo, roboflow

i'm using google colab for the detection of object  with Yolo.

in the step of the Train Custom YOLOv4 Detector, i have this error

CUDA status Error: file: ./src/blas_kernels.cu : () : line: 841 : build time: Nov 26 2020 - 16:49:52

CUDA Error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device
CUDA Error: no kernel image is available for execution on the device: File exists
darknet: ./src/utils.c:325: error: Assertion `0' failed.

can you help me please

Comment: check your has gpu enabled

Comment: Thank you for your answer i checked my gpu ans now i have this messafge error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 492, in <module>
    train(hyp, opt, device, tb_writer, wandb)
  File "train.py", line 186, in train
    image_weights=opt.image_weights)
TypeError: create_dataloader() got an unexpected keyword argument 'image_weights'
CPU times: user 48.7 ms, sys: 14 ms, total: 62.7 ms
Wall time: 19.7 s